# Smallest matroid containing two disjoint maximal elements of cardinality $K$?

Tags: matroids

Given a ground set $N=(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{K-1},b_0,b_1,\dots,b_{K-1})$ of size $2K$, what is the smallest matroid for which $A=(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{K-1})$ and $B=(b_0,b_1,\dots,b_{K-1})$ are independent sets. My intuition says it might be matroids of the form:
$$\mathcal{M}_t = (N,\mathcal{I}_t), \text{ where } \mathcal{I}_t = \{ S : S \cap \{ a_i,b_{i+t} \}^* \le 1 \}$$
but I am not able to prove/disprove this. Any thoughts on how I can approach this?

$*$ Indices are taken modulo $K$

Comment: What do you mean by *smallest matroid*?

Comment: @AaronDall By smallest matroid I mean one which has the least number of independent sets.